# Using Putty to SSH ignoring all warnings in Perl

Tags: perl, ssh, putty, plink

I'm writing a Perl script to SSH into remote linux and maci machines from a windows. For that I'm running [`plink` (putty link)](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter7.html) command using `qx`. The  problem is that when I try to run the `plink` command it gives a prompt

> The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
>   have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
>   think it is. ......  If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
>   connection. Store key in cache? (y/n)

I have to automate the process of running a command remotely. So, I somehow want to bypass this warning.

I could think of two ways of doing this but don't know how to accomplish these

- Somehow bypass this warning from putty itself through some command line options or other commands
- Some Perl way of passing input to `plink` when prompted

Can anyone suggest how to do this either in one of above ways or some other solutions.

Comment: Do you connect to arbitrary hosts? If not, you can just say "yes" manually once and it will be saved.

Comment: Yes, the hosts are machines on a network and they are arbitrary not one or two

Comment: Does `plink -batch` just fail?

Comment: It says `connection abandoned`.

Comment: Can you use a non-plink solution, e.g. [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2) or [Net::SSH::Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Perl)?

Comment: The problem is I neither do I have these modules in my system nor I can install them. Also, when I use `ssh` (instead of `plink`) it also prompts for a password

Comment: Why can't you install them?

Comment: I'm using Perl from some network location and don't have permissions to install modules there

Comment: Wow, this is like layers of WTF.

Comment: I'd expect `Expect` to help with this ...  (in case the hack you found ever fails you)

Comment: Are you sure, if we can use `Expect` on windows ?

Comment: See also [VBA Excel code using echo y with PLink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32335508/850848).

Comment: "_if we can use Expect on window_" -- good point.  These days [we can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47940226/4653379) (with Cygwin though)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using pipes to pass Y to `plink` when prompted - `echo Y | plink -ssh <user>@<host> -pw <password> <command>`.

For more details refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13617603/10202232). Also note the answer by @clay where he says

> For internal servers, the blind echo y | ... trick is probably adequate (and super simple). However, for external servers accessed over the internet, it is much more secure to accept the server host key once rather than blindly accepting every time.

This was the case with me - I was using `plink` to ssh to internal servers.

Comment: So please do not post duplicate answers. Close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: Well this is a workaround I found for my problem. But as I said there might be more Perl(ish) way of doing this thing which I don't know. Using `Expect` is one such way as suggested by @zdim - but I thought it was not compatible with windows.

Comment: Well, the more Perlish way is to use a native Perl implementation of SSH, not Plink.